# product alphabet filter option in magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, filter

Product alphabet filter option in magento 2

ref video :
https://www.loom.com/share/0b1de140088d41279ae2ec1d4222f3b2

Answer (score 0):

````
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
// Get String Name To Filter
$postdata = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('alpha');
// if postdata is not empty and not equal to all then ....
if( $postdata != '' && $postdata != 'all' )
{
// Custom Set Attribute To Filter Using Name 
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'name', 'like'=>$postdata.'%')));
}
else
{
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
}```
````

Comment: bro try this code lines put it into your block code where you your setCollection(). may this help you

Comment: bro i ask product you give order list ?

Comment: ```$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => 'h%'));```

Comment: i need every product list page

Comment: Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Store Front > Product Listing Sort by

Comment: Display Settings tab > Default Product Listing Sort By to Product Name

Comment: i need click "A" Filter in A name product , and i click "B " Filter in B name product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116365/discussion-between-kgr-and-hamza786).

Answer (score 0):

````
 public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
    {
        $filter = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar);
        if (is_array($filter)) {
            return $this;
        }

        // MP customized
        $filter = explode(',', $filter);
        if (count($filter) < 1) {
            return $this;
        } else if ($filter == '') {
            return $this;
        }

        if (count($filter) == 1) {
            $filter = $filter[0];
        }

        if ($filter == '') {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($filter) {
            $this->_initItems();
            $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
            $text = '';
            foreach ($filter as $att) {
                ($text == '') ? $text = $this->_getOptionText($att) : $text .= ', '.$this->_getOptionText($att);
            }
            if (count($filter) == 1) {
                $text = $this->_getOptionText($filter);
            }
            $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
        }
        // End MP customized
        return $this;
      }```
````